# Posting to a Facebook page via OpenGraph

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

through all the articles and guides, I can't seem to figure out how to authenticate with Facebook so that I could post from our website to our Facebook page. Can you please give me some sort of "how to do exactly this for dummies"? The main thing is that I can't figure out how to get that `acces_token`. The questions are:

1. do I need to create some sort of `facebook application` first?
2. will the app post to the page's wall as a page admin would, or as an application, in other words - how to do it as a page admin?

Comment: To make things easier, you could use a wrapper for your favorite programing language. For example, I'm developing in Java, and I use RestFB, and it works just fine. Facebook itself provide wrapper libraries for PHP, Python, etc.

Comment: The old Rest API seems to be deprecated. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/

Comment: RestFB is the name of an open-source API actually wrapping OpenGraph, even if a "Legacy Rest API" still exists. http://restfb.com/

Comment: Thank you, I thought you were talking about the old rest api.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to create a Facebook application in order to let the users of your website post their stuff on Facebook.

The authenticate process, using OAuth 2.0, is quite simple:

- call `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorizeclient_id=<your app's client_id>&redirect_uri=<your redirect URU>`. As you can see, you have to transmit your client_id and an URI where Facebook will redirect at the end of the process. You can also transmit a data parameter, which will go unchanged through the process. Useful to keep track of the user.
- call `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<your app's client_id>&redirect_uri=h<your redirect URU>&client_secret=<your app's client_secret>&code=<code>` The code parameter is given by the call to the redirect URI on the previous step
- call `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=<access_token>`, using the ad-hoc access_token returned by the previous redirect, and then you get the real **access_token**.

More infos here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Do you need more infos on publishing?

Comment: I may have explained myself wrong. What I want is to create a simple way to publish post (in example news) from the website to a facebook page and AS a facebook page.

Comment: What do you mean by "as a Facebook page"?

Comment: Another thing that I don't get is how to add that created application to my facebook page. I can't submit it to the app directory, because it won't have the required amount of users (only the web page will be using this app, or am I getting this totally wrong?).

Comment: That I won't publish this as a fan, but as the page admin (so if the page name is 'Tomatoes', it won't get published under my name, but "Tomatoes: blablalbalblabla".

Comment: When your ysers authenticate, Facebook will ask them to autorize the application, so your users will be users of your appication.

Comment: The thing to understand is: your webpage is not a Facebook user. Your users are. So when they authenticate, they will be asked to log in  in facebook (or not, if they already are), and then to autorize your application. By the way, you will have to specifiy the rights your application will need, especially if you want to publish on the users' wall. What they will publish using your website will be published under their name, with a text like "published using Acme application" or something

Comment: Yes, but do I need to get five random users to use the app just so I could add it to the actual page (or else I won't find the app in the application directory obviously)?

Comment: Traroth: I think I'm somehow explaining this the wrong way all along. Let me start over: I have this facebook page: http://www.facebook.com/pages/CServerscz/160003644037370 (call it fbpage from now). And a webpage http://www.cservers.cz (this we'll call webpage). I'm currently writing a news module for the webpage and I want that the webpage posts every new entry to the Facebook page, so this facebook application won't be for the users, but for the page only.

Comment: I have no idea about that, honestly... (was about app directory)

Comment: And you want your users to publish on the wall of this page, if I get it right...

Comment: NO, i want me, as an WEBPAGE admin to post to the FB page as fbpage admin.

Comment: To publish on your page's wall, you will have to publish on the following URL: https://graph.facebook.com/160003644037370/feed Send all comments to this URL, and they will appear on your page's wall.

Comment: Yes. But there I need an access token, which i don't know how to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out your user id and an access token from
the [opengraph explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

The following Java code (using [apache http client](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)), publishes a message on the facebook wall of the user id specified.

```
public class Main2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try {


            String accessToken = "AAACEdEose0cBANzDaBq";

            String message = "Hey Jude, don't make it bad";

            String userId = "200501511023";

            String requestURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+userId+"/feed";

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost( requestURL );

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token", accessToken));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message));


            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


            // Create a response handler
            ResponseHandler<String> rh = new ResponseHandler<String>() {

                public String handleResponse(HttpResponse hr) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
                    return "\n" + hr.getStatusLine() + "\n\n"
                        + dumpStream(hr.getEntity().getContent());
                }
            };

            System.out.println("****************************************");
            System.out.println("executing request " + httpPost.getURI());
            System.out.println("****************************************");

            String response = httpclient.execute(httpPost, rh);


            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response);
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

     public static String dumpStream(InputStream is) {
    try {

        byte[] theBytes = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(theBytes, 0, is.available());
        is.close();
        return new String(theBytes);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    return null;
} // ()
}  // class
```